# Check if is number on AVG function by case statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

```
$req = $db->prepare('SELECT AVG(CASE target WHEN ("NPS" OR "NA") THEN target ELSE NULL end) AS target, AVG(CASE planned_qty WHEN ("NA" OR "NPS") THEN null ELSE planned_qty end) AS planned_qty, AVG(CASE encap_planned WHEN ("NA" OR "NPS") THEN null ELSE encap_planned end) AS encap_planned,AVG(CASE open_wo WHEN ("NA" OR "NPS") THEN null ELSE open_wo end) AS open_wo  WHERE date_production >= CAST("'.$dateArray[0].'" AS DATE) AND date_production <= CAST("'.$dateArray[6].'" AS DATE)');
```

- ID = 1 (Primary_Key)
- Target = 700 (VARCHAR)
- Planned_qty = NA (VARCHAR)
- encap_planned = NPS (VARCHAR)
- open_wo = 2 (VARCHAR)

My query execute successfully (700 + 2)/2 = 351, it does not consider the two characters "NA" ans "NPS".

I ask to ignore all characters and calculate AVG only for numbers.

I want to use it by case statement. AVG(case ... when ... end)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses regular expressions to determine if the value is numeric:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN target REGEXP '^[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$' THEN target end) AS target,
       AVG(CASE WHEN planned_qty REGEXP '^[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$' THEN planned_qty end) AS planned_qty,
       AVG(CASE WHEN encap_planned REGEXP '^[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$' THEN encap_planned end) AS encap_planned,
       AVG(CASE WHEN open_wo REGEXP '^[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$' THEN open_wo end) AS open_wo
```

A `from` clause would help, but your question is really only about the `SELECT`.